# Not able to build an image for ZCU104 with Yocto

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, xilinx

I am trying to build my first image with Yocto for a Xilinx Eval Board ZCU104. As I am just a beginner I installed the required packages to work with Poky and stuck to the following simple steps:

1. I cloned Poky: `git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky`
2. `source oe-init-build-env`: a build directory was created.
3. In the build directory I cloned the meta-xilinx layers: `git clone git@github.com:Xilinx/meta-xilinx.git`
4. I read the `README.md` and `README.building.md` files from meta-xilinx/meta-xilinx-bsp to find what to do next.
5. I used the command `bitbake-layers add-layer` to add the following layers: `meta-xilinx-bsp`, `meta-xilinx-standalone` and `meta-xilinx-contrib`. I can see those layers in `bblayers.conf`.
6. I edited MACHINE in local.conf: `MACHINE ?= zcu104-zynqmp`
7. I think I am good to go so I call `bitbake -k core-image-minimal` and expect a succesful build.

Bitbake started to parse until it throwed the following error:

> ERROR: ParseError at
> //poky/build/meta-xilinx/meta-xilinx-bsp/recipes-bsp/uboot-device-tree/uboot-device-tree.bb:11:
> Could not inherit file classes/xsctdt.bbclass

I looked for that class under /meta-xilinx-bsp/classes and it is not there, but I found it in the meta-xilinx repository so I started wondering why I didn't get that class (among others).
Note that I did not switch to any branch yet (either yocto or meta-xilinx) and I stayed on the master branches. I gave it a second try after switching to the latest tags from both projects but I got the following error:

> ERROR: Layer xilinx is not compatible with the core layer which only
> supports these series: gatesgarth (layer is compatible with zeus)

What should I try next? Should I checkout other branches? If so, is there any index to link the right yocto and meta-xilinx branches?
Anyways, how come I am missing necessary classes from the repository when I clone it?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the branches named the same way in each layer you're using (poky included). The branches are usually named after Yocto releases. It's usually wise to avoid the master branch.

If there is no branch of a given Yocto release for a layer, look into what seems to be a recent branch and check in `conf/layer.conf` for the `LAYERSERIES_COMPAT` variable. Find a branch which has a `LAYERSERIES_COMPAT` with the Yocto release you want to use. If there are none, you'll need to add the Yocto release to said variable and fix things along the way until it compiles and everything is working fine.

c.f.: https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-LAYERSERIES_COMPAT

Comment: I checked out the rel-v2020.2 branch of meta-xilinx and as LAYER_SERIES_COMPAT="zeus", I checked out the zeus branch of Yocto. bitbake core-image-minimal threw  the same error message (missing class). Then I checked out the zeus branch of meta-xilinx just in case and bitbake seemed to be happier with it because it started to run tasks but an error occured after completing around 85% of the tasks (do_compile failed with exit code '1'). I also checked out the only tag of meta-xilinx (xilinx-v2020.1, also for Yocto zeus) but I could not build either because I got a ParseError. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you expect to be helped if you don't give logs?

Comment: Bitbake prompted like a thousand lines (way more than what I could see in a shell) concerning that single error, but the error description was just "ERROR: Task (.../poky/build/meta-xilinx/meta-xilinx-bsp/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot-xlnx_2019.2.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'". As I said I am new to Yocto  and I do not know where to find any error log.

Comment: You have a snippet on the terminal already, those "thousand lines". Bitbake also tells you where to find the logs, you just have to read the output in your terminal.

Comment: If it was that easy, I would not ask and just read de error messages... but what I see are only regular build commands and no references to any error log or simply what went wrong. Anyways, thank you for your help so far, I will look for further help somewhere else.